# Is there any way to set native AlertDialog corner radius using only styles.xml with no extra code?

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components-android, material-components

I am wondering is there any way to achieve it? Question is only about styles.xml code modifications, NOT MAKING CUSTOM DIALOG PROGRAMMATICALLY with custom layout.

Comment: I think There is't an attribute for this its default radius probably which we see in Material Card View  ..And its good to keep the Design standard strictly. If you want you can create a Custom one ...

Comment: I think it should be a way to achieve it with digging deep in styles. And yes I know that it is a good practice to keep up everything with material design, but sometimes it depends on client wishes not developer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can [customize the shape](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md#customizing-component-shapes) of [`AlertDialog`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md) component using a [Material Theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes) and the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute.

Something like:

```
  <!-- Alert Dialog -->
  <style name="MyThemeOverlayAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

It requires the version 1.1.0 of the material components library.